# django loading json data from android

Tags: android, python, json, django, view

In my client side i.e android I am creating a form to register a user using 'POST' method. That post is done in my `url(r'^register/', Register, name='registers'),` url. in my view i want to create a user using the username and password parameters provided by client side.

From client side username and password is posting in json format.

When I register a user from client side the application crashes.

Here is my view:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, render_to_response
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse
import json

def Register(request):
    print "start"
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print "begin"
        print request.body
        json_data  = json.loads(request.body())
        print json_data['username']
        print json_data['password']
        username = json_data['username']
        password = json_data['password']
        email = json_data['email']

        if User.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            response = {'success':0, 'message':'User already exists'}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
        else:
            user = User()
            user.username = username
            user.set_password(password)
            user.email = email
            user.is_active = True
            user.is_general_user = True
            user.save()
            response = {'success':1, 'message':'Thank you for being part of notify'}
            return HttpResponse(json.dumps(response), content_type='application/json')
    else:
        raise Http404
```

Here when I call the url /register/ from my computer it prints the "start" but when I call from android it is not even printing start.

When I see in the consol `"POST /register HTTP/1.1" 500 70008` is printed.
I dont know whats wrong. Can anyone guide me ??

Comment: think about using Tastypie with is a REST api for Django http://tastypieapi.org/

Comment: On what are you running your code? If you are using `runserver`, make sure you run on `0.0.0.0:xxxx`, because than its available from something that is not localhost. Also, maybe expand your logging options within your settings.

Comment: if you have debugging on it should show you more details to what is wrong. and you can post that here.

Comment: like I said I am sending information from another system i.e android.. it only show POST /register HTTP/1.1" 500 70008 in console...